# Vectorize column wise operation in octave or matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

How can I vectorize the following code? It is basically computing the mean of each column.

```
mu(1) = sum(X(:,1))/C
mu(2) = sum(X(:,2))/C
```

and this (normalized each element, each column has different mean and std): (X is 47x2. mu, sigma are both 1x2)

```
X_norm(:,1) = (X(:,1)-mu(1))/sigma(1)
X_norm(:,2) = (X(:,2)-mu(2))/sigma(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
mu = sum(X) ./ C
```

`sum` by default operates along the first dimension (on columns).

---

#### EDIT:

For the second part of the question:

```
X_norm = bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, X, mu), sigma)
```

It is similar to doing `repmat`'s, but without the memory overhead.

Comment: Yes. The solution works. I just had one more quick question. It is similar to this one, so I dont want to create duplicate thread. I put in the new edit. I will take your answer after that. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can even use `mu = mean(X)`.